# SVN how upgrade working copy

Tags: svn, upgrade, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I use STS for working with SVN. When I try upgrade (version 1.6) I received this error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Invalid operation on the current working    directory
svn: Can't upgrade 'C:\..... as it is not a pre-1.7 working copy directory
```

Can't find an entry
    svn: Missing default entry
But is sure that missed - I have add new folder.
How it can be resolved? Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You try to upgrade already 1.7 (WC-NG) working copy. But upgrade **needed only once** for **1.6** WC

Comment: How is this the answer? If upgrade isn't needed why is SVN not working and the only option available is "Upgrade working copy"?

Comment: try to reboot in this case, it helps me

Answer (score 17):

I know this question is quite old, but for people who stumble upon it like I did and are still having problems, there is one gotchya that you should be aware of:  **This command will fail if not run from the working copy root**.  In my case, I was in a sub-folder and received the error message:

```
svn: E155019: Can't upgrade '<path_to_sub_folder>' as it is not a pre-1.7 working copy root, the root is '<my_working_copy_root>'
```

Simply change to the working copy root and issue the previously mentioned

```
svn upgrade
```

All should be well, then.

Comment: I got exactly same issue: `svn: E155019: Can't upgrade 'xxxxx' as it is not a working copy root, the root is 'yyyyy'`, but how to change to the working copy root?

Comment: You don't have to alter the working copy root, you simply have to *change* to it.  If I am reading your question correctly, you simply need to `cd 'yyyyy'` and attempt your commands from there.

Comment: Hi guys! Phobos - what do you mean "Change to the working copy root?" I am in the same folder as my solution, and I am getting the same exact error when I run this command in my command line. Thanks!

Comment: @llia Change to as in "go to that directory".  Based on your usage of the word "solution" I am going to guess that you are using SVN on some flavor of Visual Studio project.  Is your solution file at the top level of your SVN repository?  You cannot be in a sub-folder for the upgrade to work.  You will have to run the above SVN command from the top level of the entire working copy _as SVN sees it_; not the "root" as Visual Studio sees it.

Comment: I tried exactly that, starting from `/` down to the actual working directory and even subfolders and I still get `Can't upgrade... as it is not a pre-1.7 working copy directory` (on Mac OS X 10.10.3).

Answer (score 1):

Carefully read the error message, for within it is contained the name of a sub-folder in your working copy that has not been upgraded for 1.7 usage. Henceforth, upgrade that specific folder:

```
svn upgrade ./[folder name]
```

(or whatever command your SVN client uses)

Comment: Good tip! I used that command in Windows. When I ran the command 1st in that folder, then it gave me the same error. Then I used `cd ..` to go up 1 level to the root folder. Then running that command there worked in the root folder. Next I used `cd folderName` to go back into the folder. When I ran the command again in the folder, it fixed the problem! SVN ran the upgrades in the folder. It takes time, but running `svn upgrade ./` from each affected folder repairs them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably upgrading you project to 1.7 didn't work..
there you'll be in big trouble since svn1.7 won't handle 1.6 projects (incredible but true oO)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following commands from command line

```
cd <working copy>
svn upgrade
```

Your internal working copy does not comply with 1.7 version