# Store a folder in svn

Tags: svn

I have a bunch of files and folders which I want versioned in svn.

The installed svn is 1.7, we recently upgraded from 1.6. I have a repository made in 1.6 that contains some of the files and folders I currently have. I checked out the repository and added the other files and folders to it, but now it can no longer update or commit. It says my version is out of date. When I try to upgrade it says the working copy is not pre-1.7.

Another solution would be to create the existing folder into a new svn repository, how would I do that?

I don't care about the history up to this point.

When searching for add folder to repository I get stuff about adding another folder to an existing repository, can't do that.

I just want to turn a random folder into a revisioned folder on svn.

Comment: Can you checkout another working copy from the repository?, Is the repository remote or local (ie. what does the url look like), can you post the cmds and the command output?

Comment: I can checkout another working copy. The repository is remote. http://svn.company.com/repos/project_name/trunk

Comment: Why has this been migrated? It's not a programming issue, it's only about working with svn.

Comment: Does it really say "version is out of date"? Can you please post the *exact* commands and error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you've already upgraded to 1.7 your repo, but copied some files from a 1.6 working copy. See [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992137/svn-how-upgrade-working-copy).

Because if I understand it well :
- You have a repo r1 in 1.6, not upgraded
- You checked out another repo r2, which is therefore in 1.7
- you copied some folders from r1 to r2, without removing the .svn, which is 1.6
- you end up with a 1.7 working copy containing 1.6 information.
- So you cannot commit, update and everything
- But you cannot upgrade, as it is already a 1.7 working copy

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it was indeed the old .svn folder remaining that broke things.